# Java mouseClicked() canvas does not update

Tags: java, mouseclick-event

I am writing a program which will move a rectangle when I click. I have a function `move()` that moves a rectangle 100-times one pixel down and wait 20ms between each move using `pause(20)`. When I call this function in `run()` everything works as I expected and an animation is shown. But when I call it from  `mouseClicked()`, the animation is not shown but I can see only the last position of the rectangle.

Attached is the code:

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends GraphicsProgram{

    private GRect rect;

    public void run() {
        rect = new GRect(20,20);
        add(rect, 0, 0);
        move();

        addMouseListeners(); 
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        move();
    }

    void move()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            rect.move(0, 1); pause(20);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the difference between calling `move()` from `run()` or from `mouseClicked()`? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Ah acm, painful memories. Try

```
public void init(){
   add(rect, 0, 0);
   rect = new GRect(20,20);
   addMouseListeners();
 }

public void run() {

}
```

I noticed the behavior as well, I should mention that it would be a good idea to get off acm as soon as possible, it is excellent for starting to learn java but it is a tool that works in a very specific way and so dirty hacks like the one blow are necessary.

This works:

```
private GRect rect;

@Override
public void init() {
    rect = new GRect(20, 20);
    add(rect, 0, 0);
    addMouseListeners();
}

public void run() {
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    move();
}

void move() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        rect.move(0, 1);
        rect.paint(getGraphics());
        paint(getGraphics());
        pause(20);
    }
}
```

The problem is that even if you move the rectangle the acm program doesn't know that it has to repaint it (I am guessing threading issues, can someone confirm?) when it is called inside the mouseevent and the repaint call is ignored so we had to force it to repaint by calling its paint method. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tested it but the result is the same.